# What's the difference between cunning, crafty and wily?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

The definitions are quite similar, but what are the differences in meaning between them, exactly?

> [cunning](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cunning?q=cunning): having or showing skill in achieving one’s ends by deceit or evasion
>
> [crafty](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crafty?q=crafty): clever at achieving one’s aims by indirect or deceitful methods
>
> [wily](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wily?q=wily): skilled at gaining an advantage, especially deceitfully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The differences are indeed very subtle.  I would say *cunning* usually denotes uncommon intelligence; *crafty* usually denotes uncommon creativity; and *wily* usually denotes uncommon skill.

Of the three, *crafty* has the weakest, most lightweight connotation.  Someone who is *cunning* might also be described as brilliant.  Someone who is *wily* may not be particularly smart or ingenious in a conventional sense; they may have developed their skill through sheer experience, or they may have strong "street sense".

Answer (score 6):

Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms says all the terms (along with sly, tricky, foxy, insidious, guileful and artful) are comparable when they mean having or showing a disposition to attain one's ends by devious or indirect means.

*Cunning* stresses the use of intelligence in circumventing; it often suggests sly inventiveness rather than a high-grade mentality, and a perverted sense of morality.

*Crafty* also implies a use of intelligence but it usually suggests a higher order of mentality than *cunning*.

*Wily* (and *guileful*) stress an attempt to ensnare or entrap; they usually imply treacherous astuteness or sagacity and a lack of scruples regarding the means to one's end.

Answer (score 0):

Cunningness based on acquiring  circumstantial favour by means of deceit even creating harms to others.
Intelligence is based on genuine methods applicable to attain the goal.

Clever is he who creat a situation or circumstance with mathematical means to get work done.

Comment: Hi Prem, welcome to ELU! Can you back your answer up with sources?